# Click to the next DIV

Tags: javascript, indexing, click, siblings

Hopefully someone can give me a hand.

I'm working on a javascript that goes through all of the divs on my page (A,B and C).

right now it animates from div A to B and B to C and restarts from the top. so far so good!

But.. I would like to get the same effect when clicking on a fixed object (the blue square '.x') outside of the div. like a navigation – rather than the div itself.

have a look and let me know if you have any advice on how to achieve this.

`alert('jsfiddle.net')` http://jsfiddle.net/RB7q5/25/

Thanks
x

Answer (score 0):

You just need to trigger the .wrap click function when .x is clicked.  The only trick is keeping $next set to the right item, so you know which one to click.

```
$(window).ready(function () {
  var $next = $('.wrap').eq(0);
  $('.x').click(function() {
    console.log($next);
    $next.trigger('click');
  });
  $('.wrap').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ind = $(this).closest('.wrap').index('.wrap');
    var $containers = $('.wrap');
    $next = $containers.eq(++ind);
    if ($next.length) {
        var where = $next.offset().top;
    } else {
        var where = $containers.filter(":first").offset().top;
        $next = $('.wrap').eq(0);
    }
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: where
    })
  })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RB7q5/26/

Comment: oh thats cool! cheers for helping out. just a quick idea. how would you set it up if you remove the clicking on the .wrap and only kept it to the .x?